# C#, How to insert a TextBox value into DataGridView current cell (Marked one)?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I made a code to GET the DGV current cell's value(Marked one - a cell inside DGV that has been chosen by a user mouse click ). Now I like to know how to do the SET code (insert TextBox's value into current cell).
This code (GET) works fine:

```
        private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
        textBxGET.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
        }
```

[image]

The problem is here where this code (SET) shows the row number (not what I want):

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = textBoxSET.Text;
        }
```

[image]

Comment: _Doesn't work_ is not a helpful problem description! - Your code works just fine! Maybe the dataGridView1.CurrentCell is not valid? - Also:YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: GET code woks fine, the problem in SET code.

Comment: WinForm as shown in the illu.

Comment: huh? I just told you it __works just fine__! Your problem must be somewhere else. Is the event even hooked up??

Comment: The problem is how to insert a value of TextBox into DGV Current Cell (Marked one, Chosen on, Clicked one).

Comment: __There is no problem here__. It must be somewhere else in your code!! Use the debugger! Does it enter the click event??

Comment: Use data-binding.

Comment: If it was showing the row number.... it would be zero (0) not 1.

Comment: the row number is 1, the index is 0

Comment: the index and row number are one in the same... zero (0)

Comment: I mean no disrespect; however, it appears you have ignored what others have been saying. “The posted code works as expected… there is something else going on.” What part of this do you not understand?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index]
                   .Cells[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Value = textBoxSET.Text;
```

[image]

Comment: Same problem it gives me the row sequence number.

Comment: This should do exactly the same as OP.

Comment: @TaW specifying row and column index may work ! but it appears it doesn't for some reason !

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        txtselectedcellvalue.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
        //txtselectedcellvalue.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if(dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
            txtselectedcellvalue.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
          //txtselectedcellvalue.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Value;
    }

    private void btnchange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = txtvaluechange.Text;
        //dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Value = txtvaluechange.Text;
    }
```

This code works fine for me. Also, @Kaj's code works perfect. Please explain your error in proper way.